# How to split a text file into smaller files with same number of rows

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, split

I have a large text file containing a list with 25000 rows.

I need to break this file into a smaller files with 2000 rows each.

So at the end I will get 12 files with 2000 rows each and 1 file with the remaining 1000 rows.

How do I automate this process?

Comment: i don't know about windows, but i would use `split -l linenumber filename prefix` in linux. May be google or [superuser](http://superuser.com/) is a better place to ask this question

Comment: I googled for a while, also found a lot of examples with linux, but I don't use one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a code in batch. Should be easy to use the "how to" in php or other languages

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set in=infile.txt
set f=1
set n=0
del out*.txt
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%in%"') do (
  set /a n+=1
  if !n! leq 2000 (
    echo(%%i >>out!f!.txt
  ) else (
    set /a "f+=1" & set /a "n=0"
  )
)
dir out*.txt
```

Comment: For some reason it creates files with only first word from the original row presented. In other words, Every keyword with 2+ words in them got chopped off after first word.

Comment: ouch - I forgot `"delims="`. Edited

Comment: By the way: this eliminates empty lines.

Comment: Brilliant, this is exactly what I was looking for and also don't need to mess with doing it server side like it would be with php. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can find this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/94083/how-to-split-large-file-on-windows) for free softwares with which you can split files

If you want this to be done programmatically, you can use vbscript. This [post](http://neilkilbride.blogspot.in/2008/02/split-text-file-with-vbscript.html) might help.